# Конструирование вектора в C++11 ломает старый код

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, конструктор, c++98

При портировании кода с C++98 на C++11 столкнулся с проблемой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "1"; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "2"; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A>(5);
}
```

Этот код должен выводить `122222`, а выводит `11111`. Почему так происходит, и как исправить?

Comment: все правильно выводит, у вас конструктор без параметров только вызывается, тут нет копирования

Comment: почему он должен выводить `122222`?

Comment: @Ildar должно быть

Comment: @timur из-за копирования

Comment: Потому что до С++11 был `explicit vector( size_type count, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`, а с С++11 до С++14 был `explicit vector( size_type count );`. А с С++14 уже `explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`. Подробнее [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Попробуйте вторым параметром передать `A()`

Comment: А зачем это исправлять? Так же на один вызов конструктора меньше получается.

Comment: Вы если хотите через `initializer_list`, то используйте списковую инициализацию. Не понятно, почему вы ожидали `122222`. `C++98` уже давно рудиментом стал.

Comment: @user7860670 мне надо портировать код и он зависит от этого поведения

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον мне не нужен initializer_list

Comment: Хах, вот оно что `const T& value = T()`. Из-за этого очень странного способа всё и было настолько плохо.

Comment: У меня нет правильных русских слов по поводу образа мышления тех, кто основал семантику поведения кода на скрытом механизме порождения..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что до С++11 у `vector` был конструктор

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

который создавал в контейнере `count` копий обьекта `value`, используя конструктор копирования для `T`. Но когда пришёл С++11, то этот конструктор был заменён на

```
vector( size_type count,
        const T& value,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Теперь, что бы сохранить поведение конструктора из С++98, необходимо передавать вторым аргументом обьект, из которого будут создаваться копии. Примерно так:

```
std::vector<A>(5, A());
```

В Вашем случае поведение изменилось, потому что Ваш код вызывает конструктор

```
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

который создает `count` обьектов, используя конструктор по умолчанию.